# How to upgrade a 2013 vspackage to visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vspackage

I am trying to upgrade a vspackage to be used  for visual studio 2015.

The vspackage I created in visual studio 2013 and it works in all prior versions

I Updated my dev box with Visual studio 2015. 
Install the Visual studio 2015 SDK.

I upgrade the solution and all project to visual studio 2015.
I then compile the project.

I finally double click on the vsix package and receive the following error from the bin debug folder of my vsix project ...

[image]

I do not see the menus for my extension in 2015...

I do in 2013 and below.

I am sure, there is something simple, I am doing incorrectly.

I also tried to create new VSIX visual studio project for 2015 which works in the debugger, but I do not see my extension when running outside of the debugger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Supported Visual Studio versions are defined in the .vsixmanifest file. If you open it in the design view and select Install Targets, the Version Range for your extensions is currently probably [12.0]. To add support for VS 2015, change it to [12.0, 14.0].

[image]